# Capture data from an excel sheet opened with pandas and tkinter in python

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas, tkinter

I am trying to work with an excel sheet using python. After opening the file I want to capture some data from a specific sheet in order to work with. Here is a sample code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import pandas as pd

root= tk.Tk()

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 300, height = 300, bg = 'lightsteelblue')
canvas1.pack()

def getExcel ():
    global data

    import_file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    data = pd.read_excel (import_file_path,sheet_name='Req Applicability Matrix')
    print (data)

browseButton_Excel = tk.Button(text='Import Excel File', command=getExcel, bg='green', fg='white', font=('helvetica', 12, 'bold'))
canvas1.create_window(150, 150, window=browseButton_Excel)

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['Requirement ID','Req Type'])
print (df)
root.mainloop()
```

I get the error in `df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['Requirement ID','Req Type'])` that the name 'data' is undefined , why is that ?

Comment: You haven't actually called `getExcel` yet.

Comment: @FelipeLanza you are right I removed these two lines: 
 df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['Requirement ID','Req Type'])
print (df)
 and put them after the root.mainloop() and now it works